# Generating the next column letter via formula

Tags: google-sheets, range, character, substitution, excel-indirect

I am trying to grab a Column letter that is written in a cell and then generate what would be the next column's letter. This works for A to Z, but after that, my formula doesn't work

Let's say Cell A1 contains letter A and I want my function to show the next possible column, here B. This works:

```
=char(CODE(A1)+1)
```

However, if A1 contains letter Z, I want it to show the next column combination AA. Of if it's AZ, I'd like it to show BA. Is there any formula that can be created to execute this function?

Comment: you want arrayformula for this too?

Comment: Hmm, what would be the benefit of an array formula here? If I copy the value to the next cell over, it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  =SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, COLUMN(INDIRECT(A2&1))+1, 4), 1, )
```

[image: 3]

Comment: Wow, works great! Would love to know how it works if you have a minute so that I can better code such solutions going forward!

Comment: sure, basicaly it creates an range with `INDIRECT` of `A2&1` (which is `Z1`) then range `Z1` is inserted into `COLUMN` which converts column Z into a number 26 then you ad +1 to it and `ADDRESS` will convert 27 into column laters (AA) or more likely a valid range `AA1` that's why you need `SUBSTITUTE` to remove that `1` and leave you with just `AA`